# Disable input type submit when input text is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code:

```
setInterval(function(){
  if($("#username_error").val() == "" && $("#password_error").val() == "" && $("#email_error").val() == ""){
    $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
    $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
  }
}, 10);
```

I need to disable the submit button if there are no errors for three divs. When I run this code, nothing happens. But if I do an `alert()` this `if` statement runs correctly. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There are many events that you can listen to instead of using `setOverkill`.

Comment: try by id for input[type="submit"] and replace setInterval to some other custom function

Comment: there can be different way than setInterval for this kind of stuff. just a suggation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');    

$('input[type="text"]').change(function(){
   if($("#username_error").val() == "" && $("#password_error").val() == "" && $("#email_error").val() == "") {
       $('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
   } else {
       $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
   }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/arvind07/3EkXm/)**

Comment: if error value is empty that means there is no error.... and thn you are making it disable... this makes no sense

Comment: @bipen I just gave him the idea of how to do it. I am not considering what these values are. It may be text field or something else.

Comment: @MaxPain I have added the demo, you can take a look at that.

Comment: ok I used `live` with `hover` but the button does not re-enable after there is no errors ? how do I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery keyup event.

```
$('input').keyup(function(){
       if($("#username_error").val() == "" && $("#password_error").val() == "" && $("#email_error").val() == "") {
         $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled',true);
       } else {
         $('input[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', false);
       }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('button').attr("disabled", true); // starts disabling the button
    $('input').on("blur", null, function () {
        if ($("#username_error").val() != "" && $("#password_error").val() != "" && $("#email_error").val() != "") {
            $("#botao").attr("disabled", false);
        } else {
            $("#botao").attr("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If "#username_error", "#password_error" and "#email_error" are three divs. Replace "val()" by "html()"